# Cat last X characters on the 14th line in a file

Tags: linux, sed, cat

I have a file with a line that has `VERSION : X.X.X`

I want to return on the console just the `X.X.X` part of the line.
Firstly I need to get the line which I'm doing with

`sed -n 14p filename.txt`

I'm just a bit lost as to how I would go about returning just the last 5 characters of the line rather than the full line.

Comment: Why not get the 3th 'column'? `awk '{print $3}'` Curious why the `sed` is preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '/VERSION/{print substr($0,length($0)-4)}' Input_file
```

***Brief explanation:*** Looking for line which has string `VERSION` and then using  `subtr` to print substring, from length-4 to till last character of line.

***On OP's question why we have to write in code `length($0)-4` NOT `length($0)-5`:*** Lets understand it in following way:

```
VERSION : X    .   X   .   X
          ^    ^   ^   ^   ^
          |    |   |   |   |
          -4  -3  -2   -1  Last character/letter of this line(so this becomes 1 character out of 5.
That's why we need to mention -4 in length($0)-4 so that it takes value till last character).
```

Comment: @Shox2711, No it will be `-4` only see the output will be `X.X.X` as follows it works fine.

Comment: @Shox2711,I have added an explanation too in my solution for `substr`.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought:

1. Reverse the line
2. cut last/first X characters
3. Reverse the line.

```
rev | cut -c-5 | rev
```

But with `sed` you can replace:

```
sed 's/.*\(.\{5\}\)$/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
sed -n '14 s/VERSION *: *//p' file
```

See the [online sed demo](https://ideone.com/8EUx1I)

With `s/VERSION *: *//`, you will simply remove the `VERSION`, 0 or more spaces, `:`, 0 or more spaces.